# What NoSQL IN-Memory database solutions currently exist in .NET?

Tags: c#, in-memory-database, nosql

What NoSQL IN-Memory databases currently exist in .NET? With support of transactions: whether model changes applied or not applied at all.

Comment: *transaction...* in NoSQL???

Comment: Umm, and what is wrong with that? You either apply document/class/model or not. Transaction support exists even in MongoDb if you ask me: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redis. If you need to run it on Windows, it doesn't officially support it, but the Microsoft Open Tech group created a Windows version targeting Win64.

It supports transactions: https://redis.io/topics/transactions

There is a nice C#/.NET Client, which allows you to talk to the Redis instance using either high or low level programming: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out ScaleOut Software too, their main in-memory database is called "StateServer" and was originally built for Windows/.NET

http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/products/stateserver/